# How to prevent the paper-ripple inside div when I click on a button

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I have a `div` with `paper-ripple` and a `button` in it. Clicking anywhere inside the `div` should play the ripple animation which is working as expected but don't want the ripple when the `button` is clicked.

Please run the code snippet below

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>  
  <link href="paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <test-elem></test-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="test-elem">
    <template>
      <style>
        div { 
          width: 150px;
          position: relative; 
          padding: 15px;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        button { color: green; border: 1px solid green;  }
      </style>
    
      
      <div>
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>  
    </template>
    
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'test-elem'})
    </script>
    
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

Comment: As in permanently disable it? Why not just remove the `<paper-ripple>` element?

Comment: @tony19 I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. `paper-ripple` listens to the `'down'` action and starts the ripple animation. So need to listen to the same action for the button and stop the event propagation.

Try the snippet below

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v1.9.2/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>  
  <link href="paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <test-elem></test-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="test-elem">
    <template>
      <style>
        div { 
          width: 150px;
          position: relative; 
          padding: 15px;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        button { color: green; border: 1px solid green;  }
      </style>
    
      
      <div>
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        <button id="btn">Button</button>
      </div>  
    </template>
    
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'test-elem',
         listeners: {'btn.down': 'onDown'},

         onDown: function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
         }
      });
    </script>
    
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just changed the HTML structure and added few lines of CSS and it will work as expected

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>  
  <link href="paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <test-elem></test-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="test-elem">
    <template>
      <style>
        div.inner { 
          width: 150px;
          height: 40px;
          position: absolute; 
          padding: 15px;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
        button {
          color: green;
          border: 1px solid green;
          position: absolute;
          top: 10%;
          left: 5%;
        }
      </style>

      <div>
        <div class="inner">
          <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        </div>  
        <button>Button</button>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
      Polymer({ is: 'test-elem'})
    </script>
    
  </dom-module>

</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, but `button` has to be inside the div